# Fastest way to manipulate strings in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'm relatively new to Objective C and I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently replace a character in a string in the case that I know the index where that character would be.

Basically if S is my string I would like to be able to do this s[i] = 'n' for some i

But this looks quite expensive to me:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,1);
NSString *newString = [S stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"n"];
```

Is it not ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for replacing one single character, copying the entire string is indeed an overkill. It's not like it would highly affect performance unless this is the bottleneck in your app, called a million times a second, but it still feels better to either use `NSMutableString` and `replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@"n"`, or simply fall back to using C strings if speed is **essential**.

Comment: How about a few hundreds times a second ?

Comment: @user1541941 still insignificant. When I write millions, I mean millions.

Answer (score 1):

H2CO3 is right. Use mutable arrays. You could also create a Category to support indexed access to your string:

**NSMutableString+Index.h**

```
@interface NSMutableString (Index)
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end
```

**NSMutableString+Index.h**

```
@implementation NSMutableString (Index)
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx {
    [self replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 1) withString:anObject];
}
@end
```

Somewhere else:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"abcdef"];
str[2] = @"X";
NSLog(str);
```

Output:

```
abXdef
```

Note: Don't forget to import your Category, where you use the indexed syntax.